# DML operations in the Apex callback method

Tags: apex, continuation, callback, spring19, dml-operations

[image]An apex method that returns a continuation object can’t perform DML. The solution given by the Salesforce developer documentation is the “perform DML operations in the Apex callback method”.
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/apex_continuations_limits.htm

I tried to do DML operations in the Apex callback method in new Continuation approach. But it was not working. Continuation was failed. 
It gave below error. What should I do for this? 
[image: Debug log of the error]

```
public with sharing class newContinuation1 {
    private static final String LONG_RUNNING_SERVICE_URL =
        'http://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/employees';
    public static List<String> requestLabel;
    public static String result; 

    @AuraEnabled(continuation=true cacheable=false)
    public static Object getstartRequest() {
        Continuation con = new Continuation(40);
        con.continuationMethod='processResponse';
        con.state='SUCCESS';
        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        req.setMethod('GET');
        req.setEndpoint(LONG_RUNNING_SERVICE_URL);
        con.addHttpRequest(req);        
        return con;
    }

    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=false)
    public static Object processResponse(List<String> labels, Object state) {

        HttpResponse response = Continuation.getResponse(labels[0]);

        String result = response.getBody();
        Account acct1 = new Account(Name='samushika333');
        try
        {
            insert acct1;
            return result;
        } catch (DmlException e) {
            System.debug('Exception'+e);
            return result;
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Is your aura method have `cacheable=true?

Comment: I did DML operation with and without @AuraEnabled (Cacheable=true) annotation. but it failed in both cases.

Comment: Is it Aura or LWC? Cause in aura if you set setCacheable as true we get same exception

Comment: Yes. I added both screenshot and the code to the original post.

Comment: This is Aura. can't we do DML operation within the callback method?

Comment: Have you found a workaround for this issue ? I'm facing a similar problem.

Comment: No. It's a limitation in direct continuation.

Comment: @AjinkyaPhadnis, DML operations in the Apex callback method works for 
**API version 49.0**

Answer (score 2):

I found a working solution for doing DML from a continuation method. According to the [documentation for Continuation Limits](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/apex_continuations_limits.htm),

> An Apex method that returns a Continuation object can’t perform Data Manipulation Language (DML) operations.

What I did to get DML to work from a continuation call was to execute another apex method in the same Javascript method that the Apex action / continuation call originated. To get the records that I need to perform DML manipulation on, I just passed the data that was return from the continuation method to the apex method that handles DML.

Here the Javascript class method:

```
import startRequest from '@salesforce/apexContinuation/CalloutHandler.startRequest';
import insertRecords from '@salesforce/apex/CalloutHandler.insertRecords';

    startRequest() {

        this.loaded = true;
        this.result = '';

        startRequest({objId: this.recordId, someId: this.Some_Id__c})
            .then(result => {

                this.result = result;
                var parsedVal = JSON.parse(result);

                this.sObjectWrapperData = parsedVal.sObjectWrapperData;
                insertRecords({Data: JSON.stringify(this.sObjectWrapperData)});

                this.loaded = false;

            })
            .catch(error => {
                this.error = error;
            });

    }
```

This is the Apex class methods:

```
/*
 * Continuation method for POST request
 * */
@AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
public static Object processResponse(List<String> labels) {

    Wrapper.ResponseWrapper Response = new Wrapper.ResponseWrapper();
    HttpResponse response = Continuation.getResponse(labels[0]);

    if(response.getBody() != null && response.getStatusCode() == 200) {
        Response.sObjectWrapperData = (Wrapper.sObjectWrapper)json.deserialize(response.getBody(),Wrapper.sObjectWrapper.class);
    }

    return json.serialize(Response);
}

/*
 * Method for handling all DML operations data
 * */
@AuraEnabled
public static String insertRecords(String Data) {

    Wrapper.ResponseWrapper Response = new Wrapper.ResponseWrapper();
    Response.sObjectWrapperData = (Wrapper.sObjectWrapper)json.deserialize(Data, Wrapper.sObjectWrapper.class);

    // List of Opportunity records to be updated or inserted.
    List<Opportunity> oppToUpsert = new List<Opportunity>();

            Opportunity o = new Opportunity();
            o.Name = 'Some Name';
            o.AccountId = 'someaccountID';
            o.CloseDate = date.today();
        }
    }

    if (!oppToUpsert .isEmpty())
        Database.upsert(oppToUpsert , false);

    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

We had the same issue for an LWC we had created, turned out it was not due to the Continuation it was because we had used the `@wire` service to make the call. I am guessing the `@wire` service forces Cacheable on which bans DMLs.

Solution, we changed the calling point to be in the `connectedCallback` and it allowed the DML.